# membership provider

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I am a new guy in Asp.net. I have one requirement of doing one asp.net application with Custom Membership provider. If you any source code of the same, please share with me. I searched alots in net. but i couldnt understand completely yet. Please help me..

Comment: So, you want code to manage a membership list? That sort of problem is extremely application-specific and domain-specific. I doubt that anyone will have some sort of ready-to-use code that they will just hand over.

Comment: What backend do you want to use? A provider that uses eg LDAP is not going to be of much use. Try be more specific with your questions and perhaps first try an implementation and then when you get stuck, ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a **Membership**, **Role**, and **Profile** providers for MongoDB (mongodb.org).

The source code is here:

https://github.com/agarcian/MongoDBASPNetProviders

I used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx (referenced in the accepted answer) as the basis for my code.

I have found that the **Membership** provider is most useful when coupled with the **Profile** provider, and sometimes with the **Role** provider.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody here will share commercial code with you.By knowing this fact,you should consider before asking your questions.

For your interest of membership,you should search for custom membership implementation

Have you checked MSDN documents?
I think they should be sufficient to understand easily with examples. 
[Implement a Custom Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx)
[Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

Comment: Yep, those two documents pretty much cover everything you need to know. Depending on what data store you are using, you might want to consider inheriting from SqlMembershipProvider rather than the base MembershipProvider and just override the methods you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good new open source Membership Provider that works with ASP.NET MVC4. Very Flexible and main dev is developing permissions system addon for it, so you can get more thne usual membership